# WPF program crashing after install

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, windows-installer

I have a WPF program written in VS2010 and everything runs fine. Created a windows installer project and built that ok. Ran the setup.exe file fine. When I come to run the installed application nothing happens for about 10 seconds then I get the program has stopped working etc.

If I go into the event viewer I can see the application has thrown the following error:

```
Application: BarcodeScanner.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
Stack:
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream()
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at BarcodeScanner.App.Main()
```

Does anybody have any idea why this could be happening?

Please let me know if you need anymore information/details.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access to a file?

> at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess)

If no try to see if your application can access to the network. It seems to have a problem of file. It can be about the configuration read file or a stream file that you try to read.

Try to put some try and catch for the file accessing!

Comment: There is a config file. The config file is in the same folder as the executable. Where would I put the try catch within the program if the issue is with reading the config file?

Comment: How you opening a file? Using stream? Enclose code block which opening a file/stream

Comment: The only file access is the configuration file using the standard .net approach. I dont have code to manually load the file I just use System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ILPrintExportPath"];

Comment: ok can you run application from the Visual Studio in debug mode? If so go in Menu -> Debug -> Exceptions and enable CLR exceptions then run in debug mode and see where exception was thrown

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

The problem was that the culture resources file was not present.